# Proving equality of Sets three sets

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

Show that for any three sets A, B, C we have that

$(A ∪ B) − C = (A − C) ∪ (B − C)$

I proved like the following:

Let $x ∈ (A ∪B )-C$

$x ∈ A $ and $x ∈ B$ and $x ∉ C $

Let $y ∈ (A − C) ∪ (B − C)$

$y ∈ A $ and $y ∈ B$ and $y ∉ C $

Since $x = y$

$(A ∪ B) − C = (A − C) ∪ (B − C)$

Is this a valid proof?

Comment: Note, $x\in (A\cup B)$ actually means that $x\in A$ **or** $x\in B$ (*possibly both but not necessarily both*).  You used the word *and* when it should have been *or* and so your logic isn't sound.  Further, you said "*since $x=y$...*" why do you say that?  There is no reason to assume that $x$ and $y$ are equal, and even if they happened to be that wouldn't necessarily prove anything.

Comment: so then how would I prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the forward direction.  I'll leave the reverse direction for you to do.

---

Let $x\in (A\cup B)\setminus C$.

This means by definition that $x\in (A\cup B)$ and $x\notin C$.

By rewriting the first condition further, this means that [$x\in A$ or $x\in B$] while at the same time $x\notin C$.

From here, suppose without loss of generality that $x\in A$.  (*It could have instead been the case that $x\in B$ was the true statement and not $x\in A$, but the arguments that follow would be effectively the same, just replacing the letters $A$ for $B$ where appropriate*).  We have then $x\in A$ and $x\notin C$.

Then by the definition of set difference, this means that $x\in (A\setminus C)$.

It follows then that $x\in (A\setminus C) \cup (B\setminus C)$.

Since we have shown that $x\in (A\cup B)\setminus C$ implies that $x\in (A\setminus C)\cup (B\setminus C)$ this effectively shows that $(A\cup B)\setminus C \subseteq (A\setminus C)\cup (B\setminus C)$

---

The reverse direction works similarly.  You may want to break into three cases however rather than just two: 1) $x$ is in $A$ but not $B$, 2) $x$ is in $B$ but not $A$, 3) $x$ is in both $A$ and $B$.  Finally, remember that $\cup$ is similar to the logical *or* while $\cap$ is similar to the logical *and*.  Don't mix them up.

Comment: for the reverse direction, can I just say: suppose $x∈A$ and $x∉B$ and $x∉C$ implies $x∈(A∪B)∖C$ ?